# Furigana breaks when dashes or hyphens are used

Tags: support, furigana, romaji

Furigana doesn't work when there's a dash or hyphen in it:

```
てんぷらや{tempura-ya}
```

てんぷらや{tempura-ya}

```
てんぷらや{tempura-ya}
```

てんぷらや{tempura-ya}

but works when there's no dash or hyphen:

```
てんぷらや{tempuraya}
```

てんぷらや{tempuraya}

Is this accidental, or by design?

While I realize that the dashes and hyphens only occur in Romaji, knowing how words are constructed (eg -san, o-/go-) can be useful in understanding the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the parent of ruby (てんぷらや in this case) by brackets (`[]`): [てんぷらや]{tempura-ya}.  You can omit brackets in some cases, but not always.